# How to print different labels in zebra printer in one batch

Tags: printing, zebra-printers, zpl

I need to print a batch of product labels in a zebra printer. I have a file that is built like this:

```
^XA
^LH30,30
^FO20,10^AF^FDAle Beer^FS
^FO20,100^BY3^BCN,100,Y,N,N
^FD574759766878^FS
^FO20,280^AF^SNSK: US/0001,1,Y^FS
^FO20,320^AF^SNC: Alcoholic,1,Y^FS
^XZ^XA
^LH30,30
^FO20,10^AF^FDCherry Cola^FS
^FO20,100^BY3^BCN,100,Y,N,N
^FD825812897457^FS
^FO20,280^AF^SNSK: US/0018,1,Y^FS
^FO20,320^AF^SNC: Soft Drinks,1,Y^FS
^XZ^XA
^LH30,30
^FO20,10^AF^FDCola^FS
^FO20,100^BY3^BCN,100,Y,N,N
^FD881108188209^FS
^FO20,280^AF^SNSK: US/0019,1,Y^FS
^FO20,320^AF^SNC: Soft Drinks,1,Y^FS
^XZ
```

So, I'm trying to send multiple labels to the printer. I don't have the machine, I am using the Zpl Printer Chrome emulator. The thing is that I only see the first label.

Is this correct? How can I print all my labels correctly?
Thanks

Comment: The problem seems to be an issue with the Zpl Printer Emulator, not your code. I also tried using the ^PQ command to print a duplicate label and the Emulator did not seem to support it.

Comment: Oh, I see... well, thats kind of a disappointment. The problem is that I don't know if it works because I don't have the machine to print... thanks for your answer, its very appreciated